# Execute a function in JQuery after 2 functions were finished

Tags: jquery

I have been struggling with this issue all day and couldn't figure out how to make a function that is relay on 2 functions results to execute right after they both finish.

I Tried doing this:

```
$.when(SetCountryAndLanguage(), GetUserRoles()).done(SetInlineManualTracking());
```

But is goes to `SetInlineManualTracking()` right away without waiting to the 2 functions to finish their jobs.
How can I execute the third function after both functions finish while keeping the async advantages?

This is function number 1:

```
 //Gets the country the user is in and later set the player language.
            function SetCountryAndLanguage() {
                $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function() {}, "jsonp").
                    done(function(response) {
                        inlineCountry = response.country;
                    }).
                    done(SetInlineManualLanguage);
            }
```

Function number 2:

```
//Gets the user roles from the db and update the tracking.
            function GetUserRoles() {
                debugger;
                $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "../Publisher/Service.asmx/SelectUserRoles",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json"
                    }).
                    done(UpdateRoles);
            }
```

And the third function that depends on the other 2 previous functions:

```
function SetInlineManualTracking() {
                debugger;
                //<!-- User tracking data -->
                window.inlineManualTracking = {
                    uid: inlineUid, // Only this field is mandatory
                    email: Cookies.get('email'),
                    username: inlineUserName,
                    name: Cookies.get('name'),
                    created: new Date().getTime() / 1000,
                    updated: new Date().getTime() / 1000,
                    group: inlineCountry,
                    roles: userRoles
                }
            }
```

Comment: Execute the functions instead of passing their references, return the promise from `$.ajax` in each function and pass the reference of `SetInlineManualTracking` to `done()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you show me what you mean by code?

Comment: I added an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the functions you execute return the promises from `$.get` and `$.ajax` respectively. Then you need to provide the reference of `SetInlineManualTracking` to `done()` instead of executing it immediately. Try this.

```
$.when(SetCountryAndLanguage(), GetUserRoles()).done(SetInlineManualTracking);

function SetCountryAndLanguage() {
    return $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function() {}, "jsonp").done(function(response) {
        inlineCountry = response.country;
    }).done(SetInlineManualLanguage);
}

function GetUserRoles() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Publisher/Service.asmx/SelectUserRoles",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(UpdateRoles);
}
```

Note that as `SetInlineManualLanguage`, `UpdateRoles` and `SetInlineManualTracking` are in `done` handlers of the requests, they may execute at the same time. This should not be an issue, unless one of them is dependant on the result of the other.

Comment: Now it works and I understand that I need to pass the AJAX promise.